# How to get value of a Lambda MemberExpression

Tags: c#, lambda

Given a Lambda Expression:

```
Define(Expression<Func<T, int>> property)
```

and used like:

```
Define(x => x.Collection.Count)
```

What is the best method of getting the value of Count? Is there an easy way with the Expression Tree or should I use reflection to parse the tree to get the PropertyInfo and GetValue()?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the following to get a delegate corresponding to your lambda:

```
var propDelegate = property.Compile();
var count = propDelegate(...);
```

propDelegate will be a `Func<T, int>`, and you can invoke it by passing in the required object of type T.

Comment: Thanks Denis, that worked. Working code given the original example: var propDelegate = property.Compile(); var count= propDelegate.DynamicInvoke(new object[] { instance } );

Comment: where is the instance from :s?